# Django: Pipfile.lock dependency installation problem

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, pipenv

I am working on a Django Project (in Docker) and use pipenv for installation of various packages. When installing the latest package, I made a mistake by using
`docker-compose exec web pipenv install dateutil` instead of `python-dateutil`, which is the correct package name.

What happened is that  the installation failed with the message that there is no package with this name. Nevertheless `dateutil` showed up in my pipfile. So I tried to remove it from the file via `docker-compose exec web pipenv uninstall dateutil` which did not work, as the package is not installed. I went on and simply deleted `dateutil` from my pipfile and installed `python-dateutil` with the correct name.

When I tried to rebuild my image afterwards I got the following error message:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (789763)…
remote: Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/bin/python: not found
remote:
remote: Output:
remote: Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/bin/python: not found
remote:
remote: Output:
remote: Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/bin/python: not found
remote:
remote: Output:
remote: Removing intermediate container 84c77fef6192
remote:  ---> 109aa5618fd4
remote: Step 8/8 : COPY . /code/
remote:  ---> 5afe012dfe80
remote: Successfully built 5afe012dfe80
remote: Successfully tagged 3c44f0505a52f77469b72b43bc40afe49fed878e:latest
```

My app still works (locally and in production), but I would like to understand (1) what would have been the correct way to solve such an incident and (2) if there is a way to solve it (=getting rid of the error messages every time I rebiuld the image) after the incident

Comment: Those errors may be a pipenv 2020.x bug: 
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4220

Comment: Also, since you do version-control your Pipfile and Pipfile.lock (you do, right?), the easiest way to recover is to reset those to a known-good state and rebuild your container(s).

Comment: yes I version-control my Pipfile and Pipfile.lock and will follow your suggestion, thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded to pipenv 2018.11.26

```
sudo python -m pip install pipenv==2018.11.26
```